PineScript plotCandles: how to plot candles dynamically
I have a set of historical data that I need to display as candles in TradingView. My usual approach is to use arrays and a for loop to achieve this, but I have realized that the plotcandle() function cannot be used within the local scope of a loop. Since I'm new to PineScript, I'm looking for guidance on the options available. Could you suggest some alternatives I could consider?"
This is an example of what I have tried:
//@version=5
indicator("CandlesTest", overlay=true)

// Configuración de la gráfica
symbol = "BTCUSDT"
interval = "5m"

var float [] openArray = array.new<float>()
array.push(openArray,63468.00000000)
array.push(openArray,63527.47000000)
array.push(openArray,63464.01000000)

var float [] high_Array = array.new<float>()
array.push(high_Array,63528.62000000)
array.push(high_Array,63550.00000000)
array.push(high_Array,63490.09000000)

var float [] low_Array = array.new<float>()
array.push(low_Array,63467.99000000)
array.push(low_Array,63464.00000000)
array.push(low_Array,63447.36000000)

var float [] closeArray = array.new<float>()
array.push(closeArray,63527.48000000)
array.push(closeArray,63464.00000000)
array.push(closeArray,63457.99000000)

// Initial date 
var startDate = input.time(defval = timestamp("10 Sep 2024 00:00 +0000"), title = "Initial data", tooltip = "Init data")
var Painting =  time >= startDate ? true : false

// Declarar variables
var float openPrice = na
var float highPrice = na
var float lowPrice = na
var float closePrice = na
var color colorAlcista = na
var color colorBajista = na
var color colorNeutro = na

//definir colores
colorAlcista := closePrice > openPrice ? color.green : na
colorBajista := closePrice < openPrice ? color.red : na
colorNeutro := closePrice == openPrice ? color.gray : na   

for i = 0 to 2 by 1
    openPrice := array.get(openArray,i)
    highPrice := array.get(high_Array,i)
    lowPrice := array.get(low_Array,i)
    closePrice := array.get(closeArray,i)
    // This line throws the error 
    plotcandle(Painting?openPrice: na,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,color=colorAlcista,wickcolor =colorAlcista,bordercolor = colorAlcista)
    plotcandle(Painting?openPrice: na,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,color=colorBajista,wickcolor =colorBajista,bordercolor = colorBajista)
    plotcandle(Painting?openPrice: na,highPrice,lowPrice,closePrice,color=colorNeutro,wickcolor =colorNeutro,bordercolor = colorNeutro)


This code doesn't works because of the Cannot use 'plotcandle' in local scope error.


You cannot call it in a local scope and it does not have an offset parameter so that function is not useful for you.
You can use a box bor the candle body and a line for the wick. So, you can create your own candle with two drawing objects and position them whereever you want.
Check this out for an example: Plot Hypothetical Future Bar using PineScript

Thanks for the response. I realize that pineScript is not designed to receive large amounts of external data. Instead, it is optimized for its own database which makes me think on other platforms to resolve this case.
